# How to Fix the Dimension Issues of features and classes from a Multilabel Classification dataset in getting the Out-of-Bag Error of a Random Forest?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, multilabel-classification

I have created a multilabel classification dataset using **[make_multilabel_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_multilabel_classification.html)** from scikit learn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification as mmc

X, Y, p_c, p_w_c = mmc(
n_samples = 1000,
n_features = 50,
n_classes = 17,
n_labels = 6,
length = 5000,
allow_unlabeled = False,
return_distributions = True,
random_state = 1
)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((X, Y))) # , columns = "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
X = df.iloc[:,:50]
Y = df.iloc[:,50:]
```

Now I also created an instance of a **Random Forest** in order for me **to obtain the OOB (Out-of-Bag) error score**.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

rf = RandomForestClassifier(
    oob_score = True,
    random_state = 50,
    warm_start = True,
    n_estimators = 200,
    verbose = 3,
    )

rf.fit(X, Y)


oob_error = 1 - rf.oob_score_

# Print the OOB error
print(f'OOB error: {oob_error:.3f}')
```

**But the problem occurs when I try to fit `X` and `Y` based from specific values of `n_features` and `n_classes` to the Random Forest**. It seems that if I set `n_classes = 17`, and `n_features to just any value`, it will produce an error which is a `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (376,2) into shape (376,)` for some odd reason, even though the dimensionality of X and Y are in proper form.

On the other hand, if I set `n_classes = 15` or `n_classes = 16`, as long as its value is less than 17, and `n_features to just any value`, **it will successfully fit `X` and `Y` to the `Random Forest` and compute the `OOB error score`**.

Currently I'm quite confused on why this error of "**could not broadcast input array**" occur, especially since I did several changes on the `n_classes` and `n_features` already but the error still occurs especially if `n_classes value` is greater than or equal to 17.

**[Full source code here at Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12cE3TryTdKRGowF-h9GkMPEqQ4aG8pgt?usp=sharing)**

**Picture of Error:**
[image: Error Picture]

May I know on which part I should fine tune on this Random Forest model in acquiring its OOB Error score since I am literally confused into which I area I should be fixing within the model. Your responses would indeed be highly appreciated! Thank you very much.